# PowerShell Splitting Excel Add-ins into Separate Workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, powershell

I am working on automating a handful of Excel reports using PowerShell and Windows Task Scheduler. There are two add-ins that I need Excel to load properly for all of our reports to work. Some of the reports use one of these add-ins, others use both.

The add-ins are PI Datalink from OsiSoft and the other is an add-in that my company designed (we'll call it Add-in2). PIDatalink is a COM add-in and Add-in2 is an Excel add-in.

Currently I am able to fully automate any reports that only use PI Datalink. When Excel opens, everything loads  fine and the report generates and emails out as planned.

For Add-in2, when I manually load the add-in into Excel, I can run any macro just fine and it shows in the Ribbon under the Add-ins dropdown menu. But when I open the same file using my PowerShell script, Add-in2 opens in a lone instance of Excel (as if I had manually opened the .xla file) and the actual file to update loads normally in a separate workbook along with the PI Datalink COM add-in loaded.

Based on all of this I know that the issue is opening the workbook from PowerShell. One thought that I had to explain this is that I am defining Excel as a COM Object in my PS script. So maybe that forces Excel to only load other COM objects into the workbook and separates the Excel add-ins, but I am not sure if this is correct or how to change this. I will also add that when this splitting occurs, the Add-in menu from Excel is only available in the workbook where Add-in2 loaded. In the COM Add-in workbook, it is impossible to load the Add-ins menu manually.

What in my script is causing Excel to load in this manner?

A couple of items for reference: 1.) there is a COM add-in version of Add-in2, but we know that it doesn't work with automation 2.) Add-in2 is really old so I am sure that is partly to blame. It does not play well with newer versions of Excel, but we've been able to make it work. 3.) PS Version 5.1, Windows 10, Excel 2016.

Here is the relevant section of my script:

```
    $FilePath = "Filepath"

    # Create an Object Excel.Application using Com interface
    $objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

    # Enable the 'visible' property so the document opens in excel
    $objExcel.Visible = $true

    # Open the Excel file and save it in $WorkBook
    $WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)

    # Run desired macros in Excel Sheet
    $objExcel.Run('Macro')

    #Close Workbook
    $WorkBook.Close($false)
    $objExcel.Quit()

    #Hide and kill Excel
    $objExcel.Visible = $false
```

Comment: Not a PowerShell developer, but I think it’s a createobject vs getobject issue. So instead of New-Object , try Select-Object.

Comment: Gave that a shot, but the issue is that PowerShell can't select an object that hasn't been defined yet. I keep looking around for different ways to open Excel without defining it as a COM object, but nothing yet.